# Globbing in list search

Tags: python, glob

Given this list:

```
aa = ['a.b.*', 'a.b.x', '*']
```

I'd like `a.b.c` to match `aa[0]` and `aa[2]` using globbing.

`glob` and `fnmatch` seem to expect filename paths to do this work.

Is there anything that implements globbing for arbitrary string searches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`fnmatch.fnmatch()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) works with *any string*, not just filenames:

```
>>> from fnmatch import fnmatch
>>> aa = ['a.b.*', 'a.b.x', '*']
>>> fnmatch('a.b.c', aa[0])
True
>>> fnmatch('a.b.c', aa[1])
False
>>> fnmatch('a.b.c', aa[2])
True
```

The first parameter is named *filename* because the glob pattern style matching is traditionally used to filter filenames. And as the documentation states, the filename separator (`/` on a POSIX system) is not special to `fnmatch()` and won't alter how a string is matched.

If you want to test if there are *any* patterns that match a given string, use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> teststring = 'a.b.c'
>>> any(fnmatch(teststring, p) for p in aa)
True
```